# Slicing a flat bitmap in Fireworks, exporting each slice with full canvas size and transparent background

Tags: layers, export, slices, adobe-fireworks

I have a large image that I want to cut up in to 25px * 25px squares. I haven't used web slices before created a square slice, copy/pasted it in all the places I needed it, then selected them all and clicked `Export Slice`. However, this gives me 25px * 25px squares. Is it possible for me to export these slices, but with the whole canvas, remaining in their correct position. What I wish to end up with is a collection of images, all the same size (as my canvas) that can be layered over one another to create the same original image.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

As nobody seems to know, I went ahead and used my development knowledge to hack a JavaScript solution together. I posted this over on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730091/programmatically-slicing-an-image-in-fireworks-and-exporting-on-whole-transparen/16730092#16730092